# img styling css

Tags: css

Is it a good practice to keep adding

```
style="padding: 0; margin: 0; display: block;"
```

to each and every image?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it's better practice to use external stylesheets to do the same thing:

```
img {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

This will target all images in which the stylesheet is loaded. This can be overridden by the use of more specific selectors, such as `id`-based (`img#theImageID` or, more simply, `#theImageID` will target an `<img id="theImageID" src="path/to/image.png" />`), or `class`-based (`img.imageClass` or, again more simply, `.imageClass`. The former will select: `<img class="imageClass" src="path/to/image.png" />` the latter will select the same element, but *also* any other element that has the same class-name).

---

**Edited** due to response/question from OP:

> [Even] in case of html emails?

HTML emails are the one special case for this rule, HTML emails typically don't load, or can't load, external stylesheets. And seem to have trouble with `style` blocks, so in that case, yes. You still have to use in-line styles. Unfortunately.

Further reading:

- [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html).
- [SitePoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/selectorref).

Comment: Most email readers doesn't load external stylesheets. So: no in case of html emails.

Comment: @user544079: I hadn't realised that you were addressing html emails in your question, in that case please see the edit (following the `hr`).

Comment: @user544079 - For future reference, it would be good to state in your post that your question is addressing emails. Otherwise, it's assumed (rightly so, IMO) that you're asking for standard web pages.

Answer (score 3):

It's surely better to create a class with the style properties, like the following:

```
img.imageclass {
    border: none;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Why it is not recommended to use inline styles. Because if you use an in-line style, you'll not be able to affect on that element from browser specific style-sheets. For example, if you create an element and see that it needs some "tweak" to look good in IE6, for example, the IE6 specific style-sheet will not work if you explicitly put an inline style for that element since the in-line style will be "lower" and thus will have higher priority.

Answer (score 0):

it is good practice, but like @David Thomas said, it's better to do it in an external CSS file to keep from inline clutters.